# AWS CLI: api gateway get-usage not returning usage of all keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to see usage of each API key in my usage plan. However when I run

```
aws apigateway get-usage --usage-plan-id ***** --start-date 2021-01-18 --end-date 2021-01-24 --profile prod --region ap-south-1 >> week04.txt
```

It returns usage of only few keys. When I try to do that from the AWS management console from here

[image: Snapshot]

It gives me the usage of the same few keys. I have to manually click every single key and generate the report which is very tedious. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: try passing `--no-paginate` to get-usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can combine `get-usage-plan-keys` and `get-usage` with `xargs` to extract for every api key at once.

```
aws apigateway  get-usage-plan-keys --usage-plan-id xx44ww | jq -r ".items[].id" | xargs -I {} aws apigateway get-usage --usage-plan-id xg4j0w --key-id {} --start-date 2021-01-01 --end-date 2021-01-24 --no-paginate > output.json
```

Breaking it down for better readability:

Getting usage plan keys:

```
aws apigateway  get-usage-plan-keys --usage-plan-id xx44ww
```

Extracting plan keys

```
| jq -r ".items[].id"
```

loop for every api key id with `xargs`

```
aws apigateway get-usage --usage-plan-id xg4j0w --key-id {} --start-date 2021-01-01 --end-date 2021-01-24 --no-paginate
```

Comment: Hi. Just wonder if you could get same with just using `--query` of aws cli, without the need for `jq` or `xargs`?

Comment: Not sure about replacing the `xargs`, but you can remove the need for jq: 
`aws apigateway get-usage-plan-keys --usage-plan-id xxxxxx --query "items[*].id" --output text | xargs -n1 aws apigateway get-usage --usage-plan-id xxxxxx --start-date YYYY-MM-DD --end-date YYYY-MM-DD --no-paginate --key-id > output.json`